# .Net Blazor benefits over Angular , React or other javascript framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

What is the main feature of Microsoft's .Net Blazor? Can we use it in place of React or Angular? Will Blazor provide all the tools which are provided in Angular or React?

Comment: You should be asking whether *WebAssembly* can be used in place of React etc. Blazor is only one tool that generates WebAssembly from server-side code

Comment: In fact, you can *combine* WebAssembly and Angular or React code, [as shown in this randomly googled article](https://componenthouse.com/2018/02/15/how-to-make-angular-and-webassembly-work-together/)

Comment: Actually, the server does not generate webassembly. The compiler does. You can host a blazor app on a static site.

Comment: @Flores that means that you can't compare them

Comment: Technically no, but feature wise you could.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

In my opinion the main advantages of using Blazor instead of React or Angular are:

- C# and ASP.NET can be used both on the client and server-side. Currently the cost of switching is high (imho) and removing the need for JavaScript libraries would reduce this. It is more or less the same argument for using Node.js on the server-side. But in the case of Blazor you remove JavaScript in favour for C# and ASP.NET. Who does not like that? :)
- You can use shared models (or even functional code) that will reduce duplicate code, will save time and prevent mistakes caused by client-server model mismatch.

It is correct that Blazor and Angular/React are in fact not the same thing. Blazor generates WebAssembly and React/Angular do not (currently). However, the first two arguments are still valid if you are thinking of replacing Angular/React with Blazor. Just keep in mind that Blazor is still not fully supported and does not have all the features that the Javascript libraries have.

Comment: thanks @MartinH , i got solution of my confusion about Blazor, yeah Blazor  still in experimental stage but still we are hopeful it gonna achieve the goal its created for....and Sorry i can not up mark your comment as my points are less than 15

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help.

Comment: You get the best developer experience on the planet in terms of tooling. For example you can use Resharper to make refactorings that you'll trust.

Comment: Visual Studio really does speed up development, and C# is IMO an excellent, and progressive language. As Mihail note, combine that with Resharper and you're life becomes a whole lot easier. I'm mostly interested in how it can make web apps more testable, because as it stands the options for testing the likes of Angular and React still seem to come down to attaching to DOM elements, or doing limited unit testing. Blazor may give us a few more options, or at least we can hope.

Comment: If implement and had server side debugging nailed down then they would have a winner for sure.

Comment: @MihailShishkov True.  It's shocking the amazing amount of configuration and tooling necessary just to get started with Angular, Vue.js and other JS Frameworks. Each tool you add to its toolchain adds to the learning curve and more often than not complicates development instead of simplifying it.

Comment: @BenPower While I haven't exercised the unit testing in Blazor, I will say it is no different from any .NET-based web technology. If you factor out the component, pages and other layers of Blazor, it's as testable as any other ASP.NET architecture.